# Wicket: DateTextField settings

Tags: java, wicket

I created some `DateTextFields`. They are working great but I want to use another language and another date format.

According to [wicket-bootstrap](http://wb.agilecoders.de/demo/datepicker#datepicker-language) I created my fields like this:

```
final DateTextField startDate = new DateTextField("startDate",  new DateTextFieldConfig().withLanguage("es");
```

but this has no effect. I searched a while, the only thing I found is I could change the default date pattern by using the constructor like this ([JavaDocs](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/datetime/markup/html/form/DateTextField.html)):

```
final DateTextField startDate = new DateTextField("startDate", "dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Both ways have no effect. Is there another way to change the language and date pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every component has method getLocale. If you want to change language you should override it. This should work when you want to change language to Slovak:

```
final DateTextField startDate = new DateTextField("startDate", "dd-MM-yyyy") {
    @Override
    public Locale getLocale() {
        return new Locale("sk", "SK");
    }
};
```

this just change language of your current component. If you want to change language to all component you should change locale of session:

```
add(new Link<Void>("goSk") {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        getSession().setLocale(new Locale("sk", "SK"));
    }
});

add(new Link<Void>("goEn") {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        getSession().setLocale(Locale.US);
    }
});
```

More information are here: http://wicket.apache.org/guide/guide/i18n.html

Comment: I thought the same, but my locale is "de", the datepicker is on english. But still the date pattern wont have an effect to the picker. The textfield still requires the 10/10/2014 pattern

Comment: and what locale is returned when you call startDate.getLocale() ?

Comment: `System.out.println("LOCAL: " + Session.get().getLocale());` returns : LOCAL: de

 ...same for startDate.getLocale()

Comment: can you try datetextField from another package? org.apache.wicket.datetime.markup.html.form.DateTextField DateTextField startDate = DateTextField.forDatePattern("startDate", "dd-MM-yyyy");

Comment: gonna try it, will take a while because it seems I need to use a `DateConverter`(whatever it is)

Comment: @monti, Use `new PatternDateConverter ( "dd-MM-yyyy", true );` as `DateConverter`

Comment: mh, the datepicker is gone now.

Comment: ah ok, I added a datepicker now. Its working, even the datepicker is on german now. Thanks for that. But now I have to validate the datefield by myself.